# Why did I lose money after a bounty was put on me?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When you put a bounty on someone, who pays the money? I had $14000 taken from my bank because someone kept putting bounties on me

Comment: How did you loose $14k for having a bounties on your head? Hospital costs? Because getting a bounty placed on you doesn't make you pay for anything (until you die).

Comment: Please write descriptive titles for your questions.

Answer (score 3):

When you place Bounties on people you have to pay the person that kills the wanted player. So you shouldn't lose money if someone has a bounty on you.

```
Wanted player : no money loss  
employer      : money loss  
killer        : money
```

Answer (score 0):

The money you lost was from being killed, not because there was a bounty on you. Whenever you die, you lose 5% of your money.

Comment: Now I understand the price variation!